# Should we store sum of values in a column, or store in memory database

Tags: database-design

I have a bunch of questions and answers and total votes of those questions and answers. My requirement that I always show how many votes for a question or a answer (and user doesn't often click to who votes for question or answer). Base on this requirement, I have two ways to implement:

1. store a column name total_vote in `question` table.
2. store total vote of a `question` on memory db such as Redis. Because this data doesn't so important (for example, I can show to user 100 votes, although currently has about 105 votes).

I want to know which is advantages and disadvantages from two above method. I which is prefer due to my business requirement.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Though reads are more common on these votes than writes. From my understanding you always load the vote count together with the question when displaying it. Therefore I would recommend storing them together.

Besides you save money because RAM requirements are lower.

- Christian